# How are the exponents in a STO-nG basis set obtained?

Tags: ab-initio-calculations, quantum-mechanics, basis-sets

STO-3G has exponent parameters which can be found in a reference book. Can these parameters be calculated using, for instance, a Hartree–Fock equation for one atom? Or using another way?

Comment: Related prior questions: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6559/7, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3728/7

Comment: Related question as well: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63560/matching-a-slater-type-wavefunction-with-a-minimal-sto-ng-gaussian-basis-set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that the STO-nG basis sets are optimized separately for each individual element (as an isolated atom, rather than as an ion or an atom within a bigger molecule). The exponents are obtained by by a least squares fit of the Gaussian orbitals to a single [Slater-type orbital (STO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater-type_orbital).

For other basis sets (not named STO-nG but named something else, like cc-pCVDZ), the exponents are calculated by doing Hartree-Fock and CISD calculations, for example.

If you want to know more about how Gaussian basis sets are optimized, you might find the following thread interesting: [Optimization of Gaussian basis sets within the Hartree-Fock Method](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3728/5).

There's also been some discussion about STO-3G specifically and why different sources have different exponent values for STO-3G: [Difference between original STO-3G and BSE STO-3G](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6559/5)